# Get cursor position, text and key in a React Native TextInput onKeyPress

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I need to get the current cursor position, the current text value and the pressed key of a `TextInput` when the text value changes, either in `onKeyPress` or in `onChangeText`.

For example, typing "A" should result in the following:

- `keyboardKey: 'A'`
- `text: 'A'`
- `cursorPosition: 1`

Then, typing "B" should result in:

- `keyboardKey: 'B'`
- `text: 'AB'`
- `cursorPosition: 2`

I tried to achieve that by listening to `onKeyPress`, `onChangeText` and `onSelectionChange` (getting `start` and `end` from `nativeEvent.selection`) but without any success as the events are probably happening asynchronously so using `useState()` or `useRef()` didn't help in order to get the latest values of the three in any of the eents.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={onChangeText}
  onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
  onSelectionChange={onSelectionChange}
/>
```

I also tried getting the text value from a reference of the `TextInput` in `onKeyPress` but this didn't work either.

Finally, tried with setting all three values as states and listening for their changes in `useEffect` but this wouldn't work because the function will get executed if any of the values change and I want this to be called only once per key press. In addition, I'm not getting the latest values of `cursorPosition` and `text` for some reason.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect', keyboardKey, cursorPosition, text)
  }, [keyboardKey, cursorPosition, text]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way you can get the cursor position value from the TextInput itself. You would have to implement it on your own. You can use the `onKeyPress` prop to check what key is pressed and increment a counter that should be in the state like so:

```
const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState(0);
const [text, setText] = useState("");

const onKeyPress = ({ nativeEvent: { key: string } }) => {
    // Logic to check what key is pressed if needed
    // Here I put +1 for this simple example, but you can put whatever value you want here
    setCursorPosition(cursorPosition + 1);
};

const onChangeText = (newText: string) => {
    setText(newText);
}

<TextInput onKeyPress={onKeyPress} onChangeText={onChangeText} />
```

You can then use the `setCursorPosition` function to update your cursor position and then read it from `cursorPosition`. Same goes for `text`.